# React/Redux foreach data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some problems with my React/Redux app. I'm successfully getting data from API, and when I take a look into Redux dev tools I can see that Redux is setup successfully, but I can't still get that data on React part.
Here is my Games.js actions part:

```
import {
    GET_GAMES_PENDING,
    GET_GAMES_SUCCESS,
    GET_GAMES_FAILED,
    GAMES_DATA,
  } from "../../constants/ActionTypes";
  import axios from 'util/Api'

  export const requestGames = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_GAMES_PENDING });
      axios.get('/games',
      ).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("Games data: ", data);
        if (data.result) {
          dispatch({ type: GET_GAMES_SUCCESS});
          dispatch({type: GAMES_DATA, payload: data.games});
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: GET_GAMES_FAILED, payload: data.error });
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        dispatch({ type: GET_GAMES_FAILED, payload: error.message });
        console.log("Error****:", error.message);
      });
    }
  };
```

As you see I have console.log to see if it is returning any data, and it is returning succesfully.

And this is index.js where I export my all actions:

```
export * from './Setting';
export * from './Auth';
export * from './Common';
export * from './Games';
```

Here is the Redux part of Games.js file:

```
import {GAMES_DATA} from "../../constants/ActionTypes";

const INIT_STATE = {
  games: [],
  isPending: true
};

export default (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case GAMES_DATA: {
      return {
        ...state,
        gamesList: action.payload,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And this is how I combine my reducers:

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {routerReducer} from "react-router-redux";
import Settings from "./Settings";
import Auth from "./Auth";
import Common from "./Common";
import Games from "./Games";


const reducers = combineReducers({
  routing: routerReducer,
  settings: Settings,
  auth: Auth,
  games: Games,
  commonData: Common,
});

export default reducers;
```

All untill now is working fine (I think), but here is the part where is returning an undefined of gamesList:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { requestGames } from '../../appRedux/actions';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    gamesList: state.requestGames,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onRequestGames: () => dispatch(requestGames())
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRequestGames();
  }

  render() {
    const { gamesList, isPending } = this.props;

    console.log("here it is" + gamesList);



    return (
      <div className='tc'>
        {gamesList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

As you see I'm trying to console.log gamesList but it's giving like `here it isundefined`. I don't have enought experience to set everything up, but still I would like to foreach that data in that file, how to do that?
Here is how backend returns /games:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "games": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "panelgameid": 71,
            "img": "https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/67/50/EkSo4r.jpg",
            "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
            "active": 1,
            "minslots": 12,
            "maxslots": 32,
            "slotincreament": 2,
            "order": 1,
            "prices": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "gameid": 1,
                    "location": "Serbia",
                    "price": 0.6
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "gameid": 1,
                    "location": "Germany",
                    "price": 0.4
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

How to foreach that data?

Comment: `reducers ` don't have key `requestGames` so mapping it to props causes `gamesList` to be undefined.

Comment: Where do I add this?

Comment: See the answer from @CodeAppretince

Comment: @Zydnar It might need to be `state.games.gamesList`, but that's just a guess. From what the OP has given, It is difficult to figure out the correct value to use from state.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice right, good eye!

Comment: @Zydnar On top of that, the inital state in `Games.js` has a key `games`, but no key `gamesList`. And `gamesList` is set in the reducer. So even my suggestion to change to `state.games.gamesList` won't quite work without additional changes.

Answer (score 3):

> As you see I'm trying to console.log gamesList but it's giving like `here it isundefined`

Work backwards from there. `gamesList` is assigned here:

```
const { gamesList, isPending } = this.props;
```

This means that `this.props.gamesList` is undefined. Working backwards one more step shows that `this.props` gets its value from `mapStateToProps()`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    gamesList: state.requestGames,
  }
}
```

But your Redux state doesn't have any key named `requestGames`.

To fix the problem, change your `mapStateToProps()` to set the `gamesList` prop to the appropriate piece from state. It is difficult to guess what that might be from what you have provided.

Note that you can find issues like these with some debugging. This is an important skill to learn while you are learning to code. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips that can get you started. You should install the React and Redux developer tools plugin in your browser so that you can inspect props and state.

Comment: I tried to change gamesList: state.requestGames, to gamesList: state.gamesList , but it's still giving the same undefined

Comment: @RadeIlijev You need to look at your redux state and determine what the correct value is. See the last paragraph of my answer for some tips on how to continue to debug the issue from here.

Comment: Well this is how Redux Dev tools like. https://prnt.sc/r8mkt1

Comment: @RadeIlijev As you can see you have `state.games.games` and `state.games.gamesList`. Either of these should work. I suggest you pick one and use the name consistently. Right now you set `state.games.games` in your initial state, but you set `state.games.gamesList` in your reducer.

Comment: @RadeIlijev Most likely you see `undefined` in the console because `state.games.gamesList` doesn't exist in your initial state. But you set it later in the reducer when the HTTP request resolves, so then it is no longer undefined.

Comment: @RadeIlijev check my answer, your combine reducer sets the object you're after to `state.games` so it would be `state.games.gameList` you'd want

Comment: @dougajmcdonald yes I changed it, and I think it''s better now, but still no progress on react part.

Answer (score 2):

In your reducer you set an initial state of:

```
{
  games: [],
  isPending: true
}
```

Then when your `GAMES_DATA` reducer is hit you set `gamesList: action.payload` where `action.payload` is your `games` property you see in `console.log()`.

In your current code, your state in the `Games` section would end up looking like this after your reducer is called.

```
{
  games: [],
  isPending: true,
  gamesList: <the data you want>
}
```

It's possible you meant to set your `action.payload` to the `games` property in your state. If so you'd want to change your reducer function to be:

```
    case GAMES_DATA: {
      return {
        ...state,
        games: action.payload,
      };
    }
```

When I look at your combine reducers, you set a property `games` to be the result of your `Games` reducer, so you'd need to access `state.games.gamesList` in `mapStateToProps` like this

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    gamesList: state.games.gamesList
  }
}
```

**(or if you meant to set `games` in the reducer, you'd access `state.games.games`)**

There are a couple of other areas where things might fall over but it's hard to tell exactly from your snippets.

**EDIT:**

In answer to you React render issue, your current code tries to output a whole object which you can't do. You must access the properties in your game object and put them into some HTML (or just a string!) to tell React how to show them.

As an example, something like:

```
  render() {
    const { gamesList, isPending } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className='tc'>
        <ul>
        {gamesList.map(game => <li>{game.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
```

}

Comment: You have much of the correct information here to point the OP in the right direction. `gamesList: state.gamesList,` is still incorrect because the reducer in `Games.js` is combined with other reducers in the global state. Most likely, it should be `gamesList: state.games.gamesList,`, but there is still the issue that the keys in the initial default state don't match what is assigned in the reducer.

Comment: When I do that I have error like:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, panelgameid, img, name, active, minslots, maxslots, slotincreament, order, prices}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
This is ss of redux dev tools, might help : https://prnt.sc/r8mkt1

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated the answer to reflect this after I noticed the combineReducers stucture

Comment: @RadeIlijev this is happening because your trying to tell React to render a pure JS object (well an array if you're console.log is accurate). in your render function you need to do something like `gamesList.map(game => <div>{game.ThePropertyYouWant}</div>)` kind of thing to get anything on screen

Comment: Okay there is some progress (I think), I have changed now mapStateToProps like state.games.games, and what @dougajmcdonald said in comment for gamesList.map like:
gamesList.map(game => <div>{game.gamesList}</div>)
    console.log("here it is" + gamesList);

and now is giving like here it is[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

I believe it's some progress :D

Comment: @RadeIlijev It sounds like we have answered your question here. If you need more help, please post a new question with your current code.